# Show that 2 curves determine segments of equal length

Tags: differential-geometry

Given the parametrized surface $\textbf{x}(u,v)=(u\cos v,u\sin v,\log \cos v + u)$, $-\frac{\pi}{2}<v<\frac{\pi}{2}$, show that the two curves $\textbf{x}(u,v_1)$, $\textbf{x}(u,v_2)$ determine segments of equal lengths on all curves $\textbf{x}(u, constant)$.

I am very confused about this problem. It seems counterintuitive to me that the two given segments would have equal lengths on $\textbf{x}(u,constant)$. (My thought is that they would be equal on a curve of the form $\textbf{x}(constant,v)$. Clearly this is incorrect, so any steering in the right direction would be helpful.

My general thought process for the proof is to use the first fundamental form to compute arc lengths for the two segments. I have that the arc length of a parametrized curve $\textbf{x}(u,v)$ is 
$$s(t)=\int_0^t \sqrt{E(u')^2+2Fu'v'+G(v')^2} dt$$

Comment: Where are the parentheses on $x_3$? Is it $\log(\cos(v+u))$ or $\log(\cos(v)+u)$  or $\log(\cos v)+u$?

Comment: @user474330 My book isn't clear, but my assumption was that it meant $\log(\cos(v+u))$. I could be wrong though, that's why I didn't include it in my question.

Comment: Let's assume that $u_{1}<u_{2}$; my interpretation of the exercise states that we need to prove that the curves $x(u,v_{0})$ have constant length for every $v_{0}\in V$ and for $u\in(u_{1},u_{2})$.

Comment: Let's calculate the length of the curve:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{u_{1}}^{u_{2}}\left|x^{\prime}(u,v_{0})\right|du & = & \int_{u_{1}}^{u_{2}}\sqrt{\cos^{2}v_{0}+\sin^{2}v_{0}+1}du\
& = & \int_{u_{1}}^{u_{2}}\sqrt{2}du\
& = & \text{constant.}
\end{eqnarray*}